# Process exchange (fortran + MPI)

Tags: fortran, mpi, send, derived-types

During the realization of the course work I have to write MPI program to solve PDE continuum mechanics. (FORTRAN)

In parallel program a big computational 3D domain (grid MxNxL) is shared between processes. Every process has it's own subdomain for computation(grid NXxNYxNZ = (M/P1)x(N/P2)x(L/P3) , P1*P2*P3 = P - number of processes). After every computation step I have to exchange two border layers between neighbor processes or (it is not important) in case if I don't have a neighbor towards I have to process the border conditions. I have wrote the following implementation, but I dont know how to get rid of extra data shuffling. I want to accelerate my code as possible.

```
    if (XB2 /= MPI_PROC_NULL) then   ! If process has right-X neighbor process
        call CopyToSb(NX-1,NX,1,NY,1,NZ,XPkgSize)
    else 
        call CopyXLevel(NX,NX+1,-1)  ! BORDER PROCESSING (NOT IMPORTANT)                                                
    end if
    call MPI_SENDRECV_REPLACE(BPtmp, 7*XPkgSize,  MPI_REAL4, XB2, 1, XB1, 1, COMM_CART, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, ierr)
    if (XB1 /= MPI_PROC_NULL) then   ! If process has left-X neighbor process
        call CopyFromSb(-1,0,1,NY,1,NZ,XPkg,XPkgSize)
        call CopyToSb(1,2,1,NY,1,NZ,XPkgSize)
    else
        call CopyXLevel(1,0,1)       ! BORDER PROCESSING (NOT IMPORTANT)                                                        
    end if
    call MPI_SENDRECV_REPLACE(BPtmp, 7*XPkgSize,  MPI_REAL4, XB1, 2, XB2, 2, COMM_CART, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, ierr)
    if (XB2 /= MPI_PROC_NULL) call CopyFromSb(NX+1,NX+2,1,NY,1,NZ,XPkg,XPkgSize) ! If process has right-X neighbor process

    if(iam /= YB1) then ! Because we have cyclic grid on Y direction
        if (YB2 /= MPI_PROC_NULL) call CopyToSb(1,NX,NY-1,NY,1,NZ,YPkgSize) ! If process has right-Y neighbor process       
        call MPI_SENDRECV_REPLACE(BPtmp, 7*YPkgSize,  MPI_REAL4, YB2, 3, YB1, 3, COMM_CART, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, ierr)
        if (YB1 /= MPI_PROC_NULL) then  ! If process has left-Y neighbor process
            call CopyFromSb(1,NX,-1,0,1,NZ,YPkg,YPkgSize)
            call CopyToSb(1,NX,1,2,1,NZ,YPkgSize)
        end if
        call MPI_SENDRECV_REPLACE(BPtmp, 7*YPkgSize,  MPI_REAL4, YB1, 4, YB2, 4, COMM_CART, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, ierr)
        if (YB2 /= MPI_PROC_NULL) call CopyFromSb(1,NX,NY+1,NY+2,1,NZ,YPkg,YPkgSize) ! If process has right-Y neighbor process
    else
        call CopyYLevel(1,NY+1,1)       ! BORDER PROCESSING (NOT IMPORTANT)                                         
        call CopyYLevel(NY,0,1)         ! BORDER PROCESSING (NOT IMPORTANT) 
        call CopyYLevel(2,NY+2,1)       ! BORDER PROCESSING (NOT IMPORTANT) 
        call CopyYLevel(NY-1,-1,1)      ! BORDER PROCESSING (NOT IMPORTANT) 
    end if

    if (ZB2 /= MPI_PROC_NULL) then
        call CopyToSb(1,NX,1,NY,NZ-1,NZ,ZPkgSize)
    else
        call CopyZLevel(NZ,NZ+1,-1)  ! BORDER PROCESSING (NOT IMPORTANT)                                                
    end if
    call MPI_SENDRECV_REPLACE(BPtmp, 7*ZPkgSize,  MPI_REAL4, ZB2, 5, ZB1, 5, COMM_CART, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, ierr)
    if (ZB1 /= MPI_PROC_NULL) then
        call CopyFromSb(1,NX,1,NY,-1,0,ZPkg,ZPkgSize)
        call CopyToSb(1,NX,1,NY,1,2,ZPkgSize)
    else
        call CopyZLevel(1,0,-1)     ! BORDER PROCESSING (NOT IMPORTANT)                                         
    end if
    call MPI_SENDRECV_REPLACE(BPtmp, 7*ZPkgSize,  MPI_REAL4, ZB1, 6, ZB2, 6, COMM_CART, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, ierr)
    if (ZB2 /= MPI_PROC_NULL) call CopyFromSb(1,NX,1,NY,NZ+1,NZ+2,ZPkg,ZPkgSize)

contains
! This is copyToSendBuffer and copyFromSendBuffer functions
! I think it is most problem part of my code. 
    subroutine CopyToSb(x1,x2,y1,y2,z1,z2,PkgSize)
        integer :: x1,x2,y1,y2,z1,z2,PkgSize
        BPtmp(1:PkgSize)                = RESHAPE(R(x1:x2,y1:y2,z1:z2),[PkgSize])
        BPtmp(PkgSize+1:2*PkgSize)      = RESHAPE(U(x1:x2,y1:y2,z1:z2),[PkgSize])
        BPtmp(2*PkgSize+1:3*PkgSize)    = RESHAPE(V(x1:x2,y1:y2,z1:z2),[PkgSize])
        BPtmp(3*PkgSize+1:4*PkgSize)    = RESHAPE(W(x1:x2,y1:y2,z1:z2),[PkgSize])
        BPtmp(4*PkgSize+1:5*PkgSize)    = RESHAPE(P(x1:x2,y1:y2,z1:z2),[PkgSize])
        BPtmp(5*PkgSize+1:6*PkgSize)    = RESHAPE(H(x1:x2,y1:y2,z1:z2),[PkgSize])
        BPtmp(6*PkgSize+1:7*PkgSize)    = RESHAPE(S(x1:x2,y1:y2,z1:z2),[PkgSize])
    end subroutine CopyToSb

    subroutine CopyFromSb(x1,x2,y1,y2,z1,z2,Pkg,PkgSize)
        integer, dimension(3) :: Pkg
        integer :: x1,x2,y1,y2,z1,z2,PkgSize
        R(x1:x2,y1:y2,z1:z2) = RESHAPE(BPtmp(1:PkgSize),Pkg)
        U(x1:x2,y1:y2,z1:z2) = RESHAPE(BPtmp(PkgSize+1:2*PkgSize),Pkg)
        V(x1:x2,y1:y2,z1:z2) = RESHAPE(BPtmp(2*PkgSize+1:3*PkgSize),Pkg)
        W(x1:x2,y1:y2,z1:z2) = RESHAPE(BPtmp(3*PkgSize+1:4*PkgSize),Pkg)
        P(x1:x2,y1:y2,z1:z2) = RESHAPE(BPtmp(4*PkgSize+1:5*PkgSize),Pkg)
        H(x1:x2,y1:y2,z1:z2) = RESHAPE(BPtmp(5*PkgSize+1:6*PkgSize),Pkg)
        S(x1:x2,y1:y2,z1:z2) = RESHAPE(BPtmp(6*PkgSize+1:7*PkgSize),Pkg)
    end subroutine CopyFromSb
end
```

The problem is that I have to excahnge slices of array like 2*NY*NZ or NX*2*NZ or NX*NY*2 but in fact I have (-1:NX+2, -1:NY+2, -1:NZ+2) arrays. It is noncontiguous problem. I know what MPI derived datatypes is, but I need some advices(examples) on my way.

Comment: Where exactly in your code you see the unnecessary transfers?

Comment: I pack 7 3-d arrays in 1-d array via copying. And after that inside  mpi-routine copying takes place. Unfortunately, MPI don't understand fortran array-slicing sintax. But i think may be there is a better way. I want to reduce or simplify copying operations, may be via creating some kind of MPI derived datatypes.

Comment: Where in your code should I look for that?

Comment: Why do you think you cannot use Fortran array slicing? Of course you can. Be careful with non-blocking transfers though.

Comment: Because, as I see, mpi works perfectly with contiguous data, and if  a slice is contiguous in memory mpi copy "number of blocks" from start address of buffer and dont care about dimensional specs (1d/2d/3d). For example, if we have a 2d square array, in fortran it stored by columns in memory. Yes, we can send a column because it stored contiguously. but, if we try to send a row it will be error. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. A contiguous temporary is created automatically in the same way it would be created when calling any other procedure with assumed size array arguments.

Comment: But feel free to try to avoid the temporary by using the derived types. I am not saying that it won't be faster.

Comment: Using derived MPI types is recommended since it might result in hardware acceleration on some platforms, e.g. networks that support gathered reads / scattered writes. Array slicing could be used with the `mpi_f08` interface when both the MPI library and the user code were built with a TS29113-aware Fortran 2008 compiler - no intermediate contiguous copy is created in that case.